# Problem with too many try catch

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Is it possible to write a method like `outType? TryDo(func, out exception, params)` that call `func(arg1,arg2,arg3,...)` which params contains `arg1,arg2,arg3,...` and then it return func return value and if any exception occurred return null and set the exception?

Can this be done better by another function signature?

for example I have 
`string Foo1(int i) { return i.ToString()}`

`void Foo2(int[] a) {throw new Exception();}`

and then call

`string t = TryDo(Foo1, out ex, {i});`

`TryDo(Foo2, out ex, {});`

-----------Edited------------------

```
        string t;
        SomeClass c;
        try
        {
            t = Foo1(4, 2, new OtherClass());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
            if (/*ex has some features*/)
                throw ex;
        }

        try
        {
            Foo2();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
            if (/*ex has some features*/)
                throw ex;
        }
        .
        .
        .
```

I want to make it like this.

```
        string t = TryDo(Foo1, out ex, {4, 2, new OtherClass());
        Examine(ex);
        SomeClass c = TryDo(Foo2, out ex, {});
        Examine(ex);
```

Comment: If you have too many try/catch blocks in your code, you're most likely doing something wrong. You should only catch the exceptions you can actually handle and let all other propagate.

Comment: +1 @ Brian Rasmussen.  Also, note that catches do not have to be nested if you're handling multiple exceptions from a single method.  E.g.:  `try { /* file i/o */ } catch (AccessDenied ex){} catch (FileNotFound ex){} catch (IOException ex){} // etc`

Comment: (And if you're doing some sort of I/O, you're always going to have a lot of error handling if robustness matters)

Comment: @brian: if I determine that the exception should be propagated after that i throw that again, dont try to answering the question by removing it.

Comment: @HPT:  Can you give us an example of what "too many try-catch" looks like in the question?

Comment: @HPT: Pardon me, but your question suggests that you're doing something wrong. Catching an exception, passing it as a parameter and then rethrowing it will destroy the original stack trace. In short that is not how exceptions are supposed to be used.

Comment: If that's the way the library you're using is designed, that's pretty much the proper way to write the code.  I'd probably complain about a poorly-designed library, but c'est la vie if that's what you've got to use.  (I assume for everyone's sake that you aren't _actually_ catching `Exception` and occasionally not re-throwing it.  That, of course, is *_evil_*.)

Comment: I wouldn't try to hide that ugliness because it'll be important for maintainers to recognize at a first glance that this is a very failure-prone piece of code.  You might consider making a method to abstract the boilerplate in your catch blocks instead, but I certainly wouldn't hide the ugliness of the try{}catch(){}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using `out` parameters unless absolutely necessary.

Here is a quote from the [Design Guidelines for Developing Framework Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229053.aspx):

> **Avoid using out or reference parameters.**
>
> Working with members that define out or reference parameters requires that the developer understand pointers, subtle differences between value types and reference types, and initialization differences between out and reference parameters.

You can instead create a return type that wraps the result of your call:

```
class CallResult<T> where T : class {
  public CallResult(T result) { Result = result; }
  public CallResult(Exception exception) { Exception = exception; }
  public T Result { get; private set; }
  public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
  public Boolean IsSuccessful { get { return Exception == null; } }
}
```

Your method could then be implemented like this:

```
CallResult<T> TryDo<T>(Func<Object[], T> action, params Object[] args) where T : class {
  try {
    return new CallResult<T>(action(args));
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    return new CallResult<T>(ex);
  }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var callResult = TryDo<String>(Foo1, 4, 2, new OtherClass());
if (!callResult.IsSuccessful)
  Examine(callResult.Exception);
```

However, if you intend to rethrow the exception in the `Examine` method loosing the stacktrace **you should really reconsider your approach**.

Comment: In general, yes.  The `bool TrySomething(params, out result);` pattern is pretty much the only well-established best-practice I'm aware of in C# with an out parameter.

Comment: @Martin: you are the only one here who try to solve the problem! tnx, If any better solution wouldn't suggest here, I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: @Martin: why avoid using out parameters?

Comment: `out` parameters are an error-prone thing in the user-space and generally don't follow industry-standard design guidelines for C# code.

Comment: compile error on Func<Object[], T>  Using the generic type `System.Func<Tresult>` requires 1 type arguments

Comment: @HPT: I have tested the code on .NET 4.0 but I don't see why you would get a compile error like that on 3.5. You need at least 3.5 to use `System.Func`.

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking indicates that you have misunderstood how exceptions should be handled. Using try/catch everywhere can produce undesired results and make your application a whole lot harder to debug.

In short, only handle exceptions in the following cases:

1. You can handle the exception and return promised result
2. Catch layer specific exceptions and replace them with more generic exceptions (`SqlException` -> `DataSourceException`)
3. Catch all is OK in the top layer
4. Catch all is OK in threads (since uncaught exceptions in threads will crash your app)

More info in my blog: http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/do-not-catch-that-exception/

**Update**

***PLEASE*** do not use `throw ex`. You are destroying the original call stack and therefore hiding where the exception was thrown originally. `throw;` is your puppy. Use it everywhere and all the time.

Comment: I Log the exception if I need to debug.

Comment: `throw;` throws the exception currently in context _without_ resetting the callstack.  This is extremely useful in _many_ debugging scenarios.

Comment: @HPT: Sure. Logging exceptions is one way to get debug information. But if you do try/catch/rethrow everywhere you're likely going to end up logging the same exception multiple times. It **will** get hard to debug the application as it grows.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

But why would you like to return a possible exception this way? You could throw further and process at the needed place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but why would you want that?

```
int? TryDo(delegate d, out Exception e, params object[] par)  
{
   try
   {
      int res = d.Invoke(par);
      e = null;
      return res;
   }  
   catch(Exception ex) { e = ex; return null; }
}
```

Comment: it just return int! how about a function that return string or a class?

Comment: d does not have `Invoke()` it does have `DynamicInvoke()`

Answer (score 0):

if you are having too many try...catch(I can't understand why) you could go for AOP to centralize the Exception handling.

Below you can find a link that explains how to use it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/ExceptionHandlingWithAOP.aspx